# How can I gather child comments in Django style templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a custom commenting engine but I can't figure out how to display the nested comments. I use a 'reply' ForeignKey to keep track of which comment it is referring to. And I'm using a level field to see what "level" comment it is.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model)
    name     = models.CharField()
    text     = models.TextFiled()

class Comment(models.Model)
    o_post   = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    reply    = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    level    = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    #others like content,author, created etc...
```

views.py

```
def PostComments(request,postpk):
    post     = Post.objects.get(pk=postpk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(o_post=post).order_by('-created')
    children = Comment.objects.filter(o_post=post).filter(level__gte=2)
    context  = {'comments':comments,'post':post,'children':children}
    return render_response(stuff)
```

Here is how I try to display everything. All the level 1 comments are visible.
child.reply returns an id, so does comment.pk, they both match 41

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{comment.content}}
    {% for child in children %}
        {%if child.reply == comment.pk %}
            {{child.content}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

No matter how I structure the for and if loops I can't figure out how to get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing entities, not `pk`:

```
{% if child.reply == comment %}
```

Comment: what!? that worked! But shouldn't the answer of 41 == 41 also pass?

Comment: I believe that that you would be comparing and instance of reply to the number 41

Comment: Printing an entity like `{{ child.reply }}` may show "41" because of the `__str__()` or `__repr__()` display.  That doesn't mean the entity is just a number.  You could have also used `{% if child.reply.id == comment.pk %}`.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to create the template without having to continue writing for loops until an arbitrary stop point of maybe 5 nest comments? I think maybe it has to be done on the views.py side with a combination of `1st child = comments_comments_reply_set` `2nd child = 1stchild_comment_reply_set` and a while loop until a break is forced by too much drilling down.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question because there's probably more than one answer.